# JQGrid: Enable/Disable textbox using Checkbox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, struts2-jquery-grid

```
<sjg:gridColumn name="newAction" index="newAction" title="New Action:" hidden="true" 
  hidedlg="true"    editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"  editrules="{edithidden:true,required:true}"/>
```

How do I add a checkbox in the same line of "newAction "so that I can enable/disable the textbox using the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkbx="<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox"/>";
$('gridColumn ').html(checkbx);
if($('#myCheckbox').prop('checked')==true)
$('#txtInput').attr('disabled',true)
else
$('#txtInput').attr('disabled',false)
```